# Circuit with both common source & common gate

Tags: analog, small-signal

I'm trying to calculate the following circuit's voltage amplification $$A_v= \frac{V_{\text{out2}}}{V_{\text{s2}}}$$ using the known topologies of common source & common gate.

On one hand, I can see that on the left there's a voltage divider with common emitter, which can result in $$A_v=\frac{R_{g1}}{R_{g1}+R_{g2}}\cdot \frac{-g_{m1}R_d}{1+g_{m1}\left(\frac{1}{g_{m2}}+R_s||R_L\right)} $$

But on the other hand the signal travels to the output through \$M_1\$'s source, in a common gate fashion, which I don't know how to take into account.

How should I analyze such a circuit?

[image: Circuit]

Comment: MOSFETs don't have emitters.

Comment: @Andyaka sorry, confused the word source with emitter.

Comment: I you haven't done so already, draw the small signal equivalent circuit. Start with the equivalent circuit of M2, note how it is a "PMOS diode", that means you can replace it with....

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I have analyzed the circuit as you have recommended, and received the correct expression. But I'm trying to figure out how could I have calculated this --without-- drawing a small signal scheme, only by using the common-source and common-gate known expressions.

Comment: *only by using the common-source and common-gate known expressions* I doubt that that's possible as this circuit isn't one of the standard configurations.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie In your opinion, is there a way to analyze this circuit without drawing an equivalent scheme? (on paper, without using a computer, etc..)